# accdb and PDO php connection error

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple connection using PDO (on localhost - xampp):

```
<?php
try{
   // Connect
   //$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=.\db\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
   $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\db\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Miasta";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        print $row['Nazwa'] .' - '. $row['IDWojewództwa'] . '<br />';
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

But then I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 63 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]General error Unable to open registry key  Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x5f8 Thread 0x1124 DBC 0x3608134 Jet.
```

any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to connect to a MS Access database in the new accdb format. But I don't believe the driver you're using supports it, or it's possible the DSN you used isn't acceptable to the driver. Try removing the `*.mdb, ` from your DSN or just using `*.mdb` without the extra `*.accdb` and see if that helps.

Comment: They should be backwards compatible anyway. The extension shouldn't matter. At least that's to my knowledge, but I figured you could try that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot vodich, here is solution:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bd\\db\\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
 PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
      Dbq=C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\db\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
```

Comment: there is small mistake in your answer
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\db\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
now i get this error
SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1044 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access ] Incorrect file name.

Comment: try this link maybe it is the same problem http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/182151-solved-pdo-connect-to-microsoft-access-database/